# Is AWS VPC CIDR shared with other accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

AWS creates default VPC with CIDR `10.0.0.0/16` or sometimes `172.31.0.0/16`.

I created another AWS account & in that also same CIDR blocks were created.

So my question is

1. If 2 accounts have same CIDR blocks then is my number of subnets available shared by other accounts?
2. For for application, should I create my own VPC rather than using default one created by AWS?

Appreciate an answer

Comment: The default CIDR block 10.0.0.0/16 is within your VPC and not shared. When creating the VPC you can change that to anything you like such as 192.168.0.0/24

Comment: then how do aws routes traffic? if 2 account has same CIDR then how does it knows where to send traffic? How does it differentiate same CIDR from 2 accounts? Thanks Sir

Comment: @Lajpat I believe you are confusing public and private IPs. That CIDR block is for private IPs that are internal to the VPC. It is used for routing traffic that is entirely inside the VPC. So there is no conflict with other VPCs or other accounts.

Comment: @Lajpat identified how? When? I don't understand what point you are trying to make or how it relates to routing traffic.

Comment: Sorry sir my confusion. Will elaborate my question once I am cleared with my doubt. Will read aws doc again. thanks for your help

Comment: When an instance is launched in your VPC the IP address allocation happens based on the private IP CIDR range that has been used during the launch of the VPC. Routing traffic is based on how you configure your ACL's/SecurityGroups/RouteTables within the VPC

Comment: its all in the name. Virtual Private Cloud. CIDR blocks in the VPC are not on the internet. They are virtual areas with blocks of addresses, your own privately demarcated area. That is why many accounts can have the same private IP in the VPC.

Answer (score 2):

Two VPCs whether in the same account or different account can have the same CIDR **BUT** you cannot route traffic between them. ie., if the instances in the VPCs  do not communicate.

If you really want to route traffic between them using internal IPs (using VPN etc.,) you **MUST** use a different CIDR, same account or different account does not matter.

If you have the same CIDR, the routing table will route the traffic internally when you intend to route it to the other VPC.